# Why order matters in hyperoperations after exponentiation?

Tags: exponentiation, hyperoperation

In first and second hyperoperations (addition and multiplication), order of two operands doesn't matter, result is same. However, it doesn't work on exponentiation. Why it does matter in exponentiation, i mean, if we try to create a law that says : "Order of operands of hyperoperations doesn't change the result", why it gets broken after exponentiation?

Or, if orders actually matters in the nature of hyperoperations, then why addition and multiplication behaves in a way that their order don't differ the result?

Comment: parentheses removal, and convention...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Are you asking why, for example, $(2^2)^4\ne2^{(2^4)}?$

Comment: Yes, the reason why when numbers are swapped the result changes unlike its predecessors.

Comment: Addition and multiplication are associative operations and are also commutative. Like most other operations, exponentiation is neither: why should it be?

Comment: All of them are just repeated times of previous operation, what makes addition and multiplication special (result doesn't changes)? Addition doesn't changes results, we repeated that and got multiplication and it doesn't as well, we repeated again and it does. Why? What happens after the that point, so it starts changing results?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845673/logical-explanation-why-exponentiation-operation-is-not-commutative-and-associat and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112612/intuitive-explanation-for-exponentiation-and-other-operators